# access to the path is denied after deployment iis

Tags: iis, deployment

I have an asp.net webapplication that uploads files from specific folder on the server. locally everything works fine, but when I deploy the application to the Webserver, I begin getting the error:

> "Access to the path "Access to the path
>   '\192.168.16.5\Files$\2\tmp\MV12148B-801_DWG1.CGM' is denied." is
>   denied".

Answer (score 1):

Shares with a "$" suffix are administrative shares and only those with administrative permissions are able to use them. More-than-likely the account under which your IIS website is running (specifically, the account under which your website's Application Pool is running) does not have administrative rights--nor should it.

I suggest giving it a "regular" share name and then you can better control the permissions associated with that share.

Give the identity--under which your Application Pool is running--write permissions to the new (regular) share that you set up.

If the Identity for your App Pool is "ApplicationPoolIdentity", then the account name to use is:

**IIS AppPool\**{*application_pool_name*}

Therefore, if your App Pool name is DefaultAppPool, then this user account name is:

**IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool**